# JQuery bring expanded image to front

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

Hi I am working with a JQuery expand image function and I needed the expanded image to be on the front overlapping others but somehow I couldn't find a way to do it, I have tried to place the z-index on multiple locations but no help, please kindly advice, thanks!:

```
<style type="text/css">     
    .growImage {position:inherit  ;width:80%;left:15px;top:15px; z-index:1;}   
    .growDiv { left: 60px; top: 60px;width:130px;height:130px;position:inherit ; z-index:-1; }
</style>

     <script type="text/javascript">

          $(document).ready(function () {


            $('.growImage').mouseover(function () {          

           $(this).stop().animate({ "width": "100%", "right": "10px", "top": "20px" }, 200, 'swing');
           }).mouseout(function () {

           $(this).stop().animate({ "width": "80%", "right": "15px", "top": "15px" }, 400, 'swing');
                   }); ;
                 });
    </script>
```

My DataList:

```
<div style="width: 414px; height: 114px;">
<div class="MostPopularHead">
<asp:Label ID="LabelTitle" runat="server" Text=" Customers who bought this also bought:"></asp:Label></div>

<div id="Div1" 
        style="padding: 10px; background-color:#EDECB3; height: 322px; width: 372px;" 
        runat="server">
    <asp:DataList ID="DataItemsList" runat="server" RepeatColumns ="3" Width="16px" 
        Height="108px" >
       <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>  
            <a class='MostPopularItemText' href='ProductDetails.aspx?productID=<%# Eval("ProductId") %>&&CategoryId=<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>'
               style="padding-right: 3px; padding-left: 3px">              
               <div class="growDiv">  
               <img class="growImage" alt="image" src='Styles/CatalogImages/Images/Thumbs/<%# Eval("ProductImage") %>'/> 
               </div></a> 
          </ItemTemplate>
       <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you make with this

```
.css('z-index', parseInt( new Date().getTime()/1000 ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

z-index will always be 'auto' unless using position of relative, absolute or fixed. Therefore, `position:inherit` will not work.

*Update your css:*

```
.growImage { position:relative; width:80%;left:15px;}   
.growDiv { 
    position:relative; left: 60px; top: 60px;width:130px;height:130px; 
}
```

Now, I made a JSFiddle to show that I got it working but I had to modify the HTML structure a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/Dpzur/4/

You will need to view the source created by your .aspx page to see how many divs, starting from any div with class: 'growDiv', that you must traverse upwards through until you are at the div element that represents its parent "ItemTemplate"..  so you will need to modify my jQuery:

```
$(this).closest('.growDiv').first().css('z-index', 2);
```

to:

```
$(this).closest('.growDiv').first().closest('div').closest('div').css('z-index', 2);
```

, where you add in a `.closest('div)` for each div element that you need to traverse upwards through the DOM. Make sense?